# Canvas to span entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Building a website for my photography and I'm struggling to make the back ground canvas span the entire height of the page. Also the stars inside the canvas become elongated sometimes - you have to refresh to make them the correct size.

The html code for the canvas :

```
  <body>
   <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <header>
```

css code :

```
canvas {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 z-index:-1;
 background: #111;
}
```

Link to page: https://benjamintgibbs.github.io/benjaminAstro.github.io/

Image: [image: Doesn't span page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you would like the canvas to serve as a background image. why not position the element fixed to the screen?

example `position:fixed` (you have already set width and height of 100%)

```
   #canvas{
    position: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: This worked thanks. I did have to add some margin to the top.

Comment: Glad to hear.. :D

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, change the following:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  /* position: relative; */
  top: 60px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  /* padding-bottom: 30px; */
}
```

Having the position of your container be relative and the padding bottom is creating the whitespace at the bottom.

Comment: There's still a small amount of white space when I remove the relative positioning and padding-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the elongated stars - I added a load function at the beginning of my JS:

```
  window.onload = function() {

     // canvas shiz
 }
```